# C free(): invalid pointer allocated in other function

Tags: c

I'm new in StackOverflow. I'm learning C pointer now.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int alloc(int* p){
    p = (int*) malloc (sizeof(int));
    if(!p){
        puts("fail\n");
        return 0;
    }
    *p = 4;
    printf("%d\n",*p);
    return 1;
}

int main(){

    int* pointer;

    if(!alloc(pointer)){
        return -1;
    }else{

        printf("%d\n",*pointer);
    }

    free(pointer);

    return 0;
}
```

I compile with: gcc -o main main.c

error: free(): invalid pointer: 0xb77ac000 ***

what's wrong with my code?

Comment: you never change `pointer`

Comment: Also, you [shouldn't cast the value returned by `malloc`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arguments in C are **always** passed **by value**. So, when you call `alloc(pointer)`, you just pass in whatever garbage value `pointer` contains. Inside the function, the assignment `p = (int*)...` only modifies the local variable/argument `p`. Instead, you need to pass the *address* of `pointer` into `alloc`, like so:

```
int alloc(int **p) {
    *p = malloc(sizeof(int)); // side note - notice the lack of a cast
    ...
    **p = 4; // <---- notice the double indirection here
    printf("%d\n", **p); // <---- same here
    return 1;
}
```

In main, you would call `alloc` like this:

```
if (!(alloc(&pointer))) {
    ....
```

Then, your code will work.

Comment: malloc(sizeof(int)) work. Why malloc(sizeof(int*)) ?

Comment: @Drew: `sizeof **p` would be even better.

Answer (score 1):

Everything in C is pass-by-value. This means that functions **always** operate on their own local copy of what you pass in to the function. Usually pointers are a good way to mimic a pass-by-reference scheme because a pointer and a copy of that pointer both contain the same memory address. In other words, a pointer and its copy both point to the same space.

In your code the issue is that the function alloc gets its own local copy of the pointer you're passing in. So when you do `p = (int*) malloc (sizeof(int));` you're changing the value of `p` to be a new memory address, but the value of `pointer` in `main` remains unchanged.

You can get around this by passing a pointer-to-a-pointer, or by returning the new value of `p`.

Answer (score 1):

You have two major problems in your code.

First, the `alloc` function creates a pointer via `malloc`, but never frees it, nor does it return the pointer to the calling function. This guarantees the memory the pointer addresses can never be freed up via the `free` command, and you now have memory leaks.

Second, the variable, `int* pointer` in `main`, is not being modified as you would think. In C, function arguments are "passed by value". You have two ways to address this problem:

1. Pass a pointer to the variable you want to modify (in your case, a pointer to a pointer to an int)
2. Have the function return the pointer to the function that called it.

Here are two implementations of my recommendations:

**Approach 1**

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int alloc(int** p);

int alloc(int** p) {
   if (!p) {
      printf("Invalid argument\n");
      return (-1);
   }
   if ((*p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int))) == NULL) {
      printf("Memory allocation error\n");
      return (-1);
   }
   **p = 123;
   printf("p:%p - *p:%p - **p:%d\n", p, *p, **p);
   return 0;
}

int main(){
   int* pointer;

   if(alloc(&pointer) != 0){
      printf("Error calling function\n");
   }else{
      printf("&pointer:%p- pointer:%p- *pointer:%d\n", &pointer, pointer, *pointer);
   }

   free(pointer);

   return 0;
}
```

**Sample Run for Approach 1**

---

```
p:0xbfbea07c - *p:0x8656008 - **p:123
&pointer:0xbfbea07cointer - pointer:0x8656008ointer - *pointer:123
```

**Approach 2**

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int* alloc(void) {
   int* p;
   if ((p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int))) == NULL) {
      printf("Memory allocation error\n");
      return (NULL);
   }
   *p = 123;
   printf("p:%p - *p:%d\n", p, *p);
   return p;
}

int main(){
   int* pointer = alloc();

   if(pointer == NULL) {
      printf("Error calling function\n");
   }else{
      printf("&pointer:%p- pointer:%p- *pointer:%d\n", &pointer, pointer, *pointer);
   }

   free(pointer);
   pointer = NULL;

   return 0;
}
```

**Sample Run for Approach 2**

---

```
p:0x858e008 - *p:123
&pointer:0xbf9bb1ac- pointer:0x858e008- *pointer:123
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the pointer by value into your `alloc` function. Although that function takes a pointer to an int, that pointer itself cannot be modified by the function. If you make `alloc` accept  `**p`, set `*p = ...`, and pass in `&pointer` from main, it should work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int alloc(int** p){
  *p = (int*) malloc (sizeof(int)); 
  if(!*p){
    puts("fail\n"); 
    return 0; 
  } 
  **p = 4; 
  printf("%d\n",**p);
  return 1; 
} 
int main() { 
  int* pointer; 
  if(!alloc(&pointer)){ 
    return -1;
  } else { 
    printf("%d\n",*pointer);
  } 
  free(pointer);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a function to write to a non-array parameter of type `T`, you must pass a pointer to that parameter.

```
void func( T *ptr )
{
  *ptr = new_value;
}

void foo ( void )
{
  T var;
  func( &var ); // writes new value to var
}
```

If `T` is a pointer type `Q *`, it would look like

```
void func( Q **ptr )
{
  *ptr = new_pointer_value;
}

void foo ( void )
{
  Q *var;
  func( &var ); // writes new pointer value to var
}
```

If `Q` is a pointer type `R *`, you would get

```
void func( R ***ptr )
{
  *ptr = new_pointer_to_pointer_value;
}

void foo ( void )
{
  R **var;
  func( &var ); // writes new pointer to pointer value to var
}
```

The pattern is the same in all three cases; you're passing the *address* of the variable `var`, so the formal parameter `ptr` has to have one more level of indirection than the actual parameter `var`.

One sylistic nit: instead of writing

```
p = (int *) malloc( sizeof (int) );
```

use

```
p = malloc( sizeof *p );
```

instead.

In C (as of the 1989 standard), you don't need to cast the result of `malloc`; `void` pointers can be assigned to other pointer types and vice versa without needing a cast (this is *not* true in C++, but if you're writing C++, you should be using the `new` operator instead of `malloc` anyway).  Also, under the 1989 version of the language, using the cast would mask a bug if you forgot to include `stdlib.h` or otherwise didn't have a declaration for `malloc` in scope.  That hasn't been a problem since the 1999 version, though, so now it's more a matter of readability than anything else.

The type of the expression `*p` is `int`, so the result of `sizeof *p` is the same as the result of `sizeof (int)`.  This way, if you ever change the type of `p`, you don't have to modify the `malloc` call.

To allocate an array of values, you'd use something like

```
T *p = malloc( sizeof *p * NUM_ELEMENTS );
```

or, if you want everything to be zeroed out initially, use

```
T *p = calloc( sizeof *p, NUM_ELEMENTS );
```