# move to next string in function and print it in main function(c)

Tags: c

I accept string from a user then print split string words using space and print it inside a function at second iteration `pch="*"` but when it is called inside `main` it still has select.

How to make change in function appear in main function?

```
void moveNext(char * pch)
{           
    pch=strtok(NULL," ");        
}

int main()
{

    char * str;
    clrscr();

    printf("\n please enter sql comm.....\n");
    flushall();
    gets(str);
    //user has enterd that string select * from std
    pch = strtok(str," ");
    while(pch != NULL)
    {
         printf("%s",pch);
         moveNext(pch);
    }

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First  of all,use `fgets` instead of `gets`

Comment: ...and format your code properly.

Comment: what are you trying to do here? Please ask your question

Comment: user enter string after each word there is space like that
select * from std
i want to print select then print * then print from then print std 

i create function that called moveNext  to move to next word after space but when i print it print select only not all words

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25204576/694576 (for an `int*` but a `char*`)

Comment: @CoolGuy why  and i don't know the size of string the user will enter it ??

Comment: @MohammedAbdElrahman , [`gets` is dangerous](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-dangerous-why-should-it-not-be-used) and allocate memory for `*str` using `malloc`

Comment: @alk please note that the question you marked as duplicated not the same as my question

Answer (score 0):

The below code will help you to get rid of the function movenext

```
int main()
{
   char *p; 
   char a[20];
   printf("ENter name:\n");
   fgets(a,20,stdin);

   p = strtok(a," ");
   while( p  != NULL)
   {   
      printf("%s ",p);
      p = strtok(NULL," ");
   }   
}
```

Comment: what if user entered string size > 20 ??

Comment: You can increase the size of the array to your wish this is just an example

Comment: what i mean is that i dont know the size of string user will enter ?

Comment: Ok then you can do it this way. Initially do a malloc for some size and keep doing realloc until you allocate whole input