# Realloc variable sized 2D array passed as parameter - C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

First of all I want to apologize if this is a repeated question. But I could not find any answer explaining how to do this correctly with a variable sized array.

Going straight to the code, I've got this:

```
void f(int[][2]);

int main(void)
{
  int (*obsF)[2] = malloc(sizeof(int)); //I reserve some memory so I can pass 
  f(obsF);                              //the array to f, since I don't know
  free(obsF);                           //its size until later working with f. 
}

void f(int obsF[][2])
{
  obsF = realloc(obsF, sizeof(int[5][2])); //The 5 is just as an example.
  // do stuff with obsF                    //I won't know this number until
}                                          //later in f.
```

Testing this with valgrind threw that that `free(obsF);` is an invalid free().

Now, if I do the same but everything in the main function like this:

```
int main(void)
{
  int (*obsF)[2] = malloc(sizeof(int));
  obsF = realloc(obsF, sizeof(int[5][2]));
  free(obsF);
}
```

Valgrind tests passed successfully with no errors.

I would like to know why this is happening and how to realloc my 2D array inside function and be able to free it from main correctly.

Any other better approach or solution is well received, as long as I can use obsF as a 2D array inside f and modify it as I wish and then use it in main.

Thanks.-

Comment: In C all function args are **passed by value**. So `obsF = realloc()` will not change the caller's pointer value and hence the `free` call in `main` is operating on an already freed pointer.

Comment: Note that you can allocate a null pointer to pass to `realloc`.

Comment: @kaylum I understood that when passing arrays as parameters C treats them as pointers. So I thought I was working on the same pointer.

Comment: Looking for a better dup but here is one for now: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25204576/c-free-invalid-pointer-allocated-in-other-function

Comment: @kaylum how about converting your comment to the answer

Comment: @LegendofPedro could you elaborate a little more please?

Comment: @atm Don't want to add yet another answer. There must be dups. Looking.

Comment: It's the same *value* but not the same variable. `obsF = realloc(obsF, sizeof(int[5][2]));` overwrites the argument and then throws it away, leavign a memory leak, and you then try to `free` what was already freed (not the leak).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing address contained by pointer using function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13431108/changing-address-contained-by-pointer-using-function)

Comment: @kaylum helps me to understand my mistake, but it doesn't answer totally my question.

Comment: @Santiago see https://stackoverflow.com/q/12134315/5495906

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C passes arguments by value, not by reference. When you pass the `obsF` pointer to `f` and reallocate it, you change the value of the `obsF` parameter in the `f` function, but the variable in the `main` function (which determined the parameter's initial value) still holds the old pointer, which has been invalidated by the reallocation.

To fix this, you can pass a *pointer* to the `obsF` variable to `f`, and dereference that pointer to access the variable:

```
void f(int **obsF)
{
  *obsF = realloc(*obsF, sizeof(int[5][2]));
  // do stuff with obsF
}
```

And then call `f` as:

```
int main(void)
{
  int *obsF = malloc(sizeof(int));
  f(&obsF);
  free(obsF);
}
```

This way, the value of the `obsF` variable inside `main` will be updated after the call to `f` and the correct pointer will be freed.

Comment: How would be the correct way to write the prototype of f? Because I cannot get it to work.

Comment: I changed the example to use a plain `int *` instead of `int (*)[][]`; it should compile now.

Comment: I did not see that. Thank you very much. I can then cast the array to a 2D array, and free the old one, because it's what my program needs to handle. You helped me to solve my problem.-